# WebOTP alternative

Tags: javascript, authentication, sms, multi-factor-authentication

I would like to know if there is an alternative to the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebOTP_API

Andd here: https://wicg.github.io/web-otp/

I would like to read SMS OTP and autofill it in the mobile browser automatically.
The problem is that the WebOTP requires a format for autocomplete that is not aligned with what we use.
Their required format is as follows: https://web.dev/web-otp/#format
We should add a domain at the end of the message, and we don't have it.

Is there any workaround or alternative to it?